# Struggling to do anything with docker.io

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, dns, docker

I've recently had to commission a new NAS and I am running into a problem with docker.  The `login`s, `pull`s, or `run`s I do fail with:

> Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally docker: Error response
> from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request
> canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while
> awaiting headers). See 'docker run --help'.

The only way I can get it to work is if I change `/etc/resolv.conf` to use google nameservers, but that's just a bandage.  On my local network I've whitelisted every docker domain I could find.

```
download.docker.com
registry-1.docker.io
production.cloudfare.docker.com
index.docker.io
```

Here's `nslookup https://registry-1.docker.io`

```
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; no servers could be reached
```

Here's `sudo resolvectl status`:

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (eno1) Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported    DNS Servers: 192.168.9.1
    DNS Domain: LeveNet

Link 3 (eno2) Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (docker0) Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 7 (br-9e6a1065404c) Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 43 (vethb895f20) Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 45 (vethe54eaf2) Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 47 (veth20ea475) Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 59 (veth8c0dc14) Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 75 (veth3089223) Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

What's strange here is that even when I point the router to use google DNS, the server still fails to work with docker.io.  The ONLY bandaid that works is when I change resolv.conf.

I don't pretend network guru and I just don't know how to fix this permanently without affecting other things that run just fine.  This problem is absolutely exclusive to this NAS - as far as I can tell every other system on the network has zero issues working with docker.io.  How do I fix this?